# How to Wget the JDK 7u11?

Tags: download, java, wget

I would like to download the [latest update 11 of JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) from the Oracle page using the command/tool Wget, but I can't figure how ?

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u11-b21/jdk-7u11-macosx-x64.dmg
```

Comment: Paste that link into a browser and you will see Oracle's message about what they don't like about using it "out of the blue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle products requires licence agreement clicked before downloading, that's why it will not work with wget without special care.

There are several ways of downloading Oracle products with wget. Mostly you will come across to the method of copying cookie file to your server and use it with wget, but it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

*The easiest way i have found to donwload an Oracle product through console using wget is the following steps.*

## Easiest way of downloading

1. Use any graphical browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.) on any machine to accept license agreement of  the product you meant to download and start downloading the file
2. Cancel download right away, right click on download progress to copy download url
3. Use the link you have copied at step2 and just download with wget in a normal way

   ```
   wget URL_YOU_HAVE_COPIED
   ```

Apparently there is a timeout duration before the URL gets invalid after you start copy on the browser. Not sure how much is that time. But it worked like a charm every i have used it.

Any easier methods anyone has ? Please let use know.